# Memory management creating an NSDictionary with NSMutableArrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, memory-management

I'm having problem understanding memory management when creating a dictionary with mutable arrays. I'm using the ios6 SDK with deployment target 5.1.

In the implementation of the class "Group" the method "namesAndEmails" builds an array "emails" that contains the emails addresses for Person objects with an email. If the Person object does not have an email the Person name is added to another array "namesWithNoEmail". The arrays are returned in a dictionary.

```
#import "Group.h"
@implementation Group 

-(NSDictionary*) namesAndEmails {
    NSMutableArray  *emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] ;
    NSMutableArray  *namesWithNoEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    NSString *email;
    NSString *name;
    for (Person *p in allPersons) {
        email = p.email;
        name = p.name;
        if ([email length]==0) {
            [namesWithNoEmail addObject:name];
        } else {
            [emails addObject:email];
        }
    }
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"emails",@"names", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:emails, namesWithNoEmail, nil];
    //[emails release];
    //[namesWithNoEmail release];

     return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
}
```

Somewhere else in the code I wish to send an email to a group of people so I call the emailGroup method which gets a dictionary out by calling "namesAndEmails" on the group.

```
-(void) emailGroup:(Group*) g {

    NSDictionary *emailInfo = [g namesAndEmails];
    guestsWithNoEmail = [emailInfo objectForKey:@"names"];
    guestEmails = [emailInfo objectForKey:@"emails"];

   int nGuestsWithNoEmail = [guestsWithNoEmail count];

   if (nGuestsWithNoEmail > 0) {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No emails" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
      [alert show];
   }

    // some more code here


    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:subject];
    [picker setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
    [picker setToRecipients:guestEmails];
    [[self delegate ] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

As far as I understand [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] in "namesAndEmails" returns an autoreleased dictionary. But why does my code crash if I release the "emails" and "namesWithNoEmail" arrays? I thought that the dictionary would have ownership of the array after they are added and therefore it would be safe to release the arrays in the method. I guess that's not correct, but why?

Is the a more clean way of doing this? Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but with iOS6 and deploying for 5.1, why would you not use ARC?

Comment: Can you post more details about the crash? Your memory management looks fine. Also, you should use `[email length]` to get the length of an NSString (what is `len()`?).

Comment: @Andrew I get a Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to access the arrays in the dictionary. But only when I use the two release lines that are commented out in the code above. len() was python - sorry about that :-)

Comment: @Paul Thanks. Probably I should but right now I just want to understand this problem.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you access the arrays? Like I said, nothing about what you've posted (other than len()) is wrong. Or, is the code in your question the *actual* code you're compiling? len() being there makes me think not. Please copy/paste the real code in question.

Comment: Jacobs, what give you [emails retainCount] at line     //[emails release]; ?

Comment: @MrBonjour The retain count is 2 as I would expect. If I create the return dictionary in a separate line ie NSDictionary *outDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys] the retain count is bumped to 3 and I can release without a crash (the retain count is then decremented to 2 before I return).

Comment: Ok, then maybe it's what you have inside the dictionary who actually do a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal. Do a simple test: instead of "allPersons", store a simple objet inside (say a [NSNull null]), and watch if there is still bad memory crash. My other theory is [initWithCapacity: 0], if i remember i have already have issue when initializing a container with 0 capacity. Try [initWithCapacity: 1], if my first statement was wrong.

Comment: @MrBonjour [emails addObject:[NSNull null]] and [emails addObject:@"mail@mail.com"] both give a crash irrespective of whether I initWithCapacity:0 or 1. OK, I must be overlooking something else in my code. Thanks for your help everyone. I'll post an update when I find the problem

Comment: And you're not actually using ARC? If no, do a test: allocAndInit your array, and release it just after, whiteout nothing else instruction. If you have still having problem, i fear that you'll need to make a depth gdb session

Comment: Nope not using ARC. It turns out that I present a UIAlert in certain cases and it is only then that I get the crash. And yes in the post I did remove a lot of code that I didn't think was important such as the UIAlert... Anyway, what solves the problem is making a mutable copy of guestsWithNoEmail and guestEmails. So now that I create these arrays like guestsWithNoEmail = [[emailInfo objectForKey:@"names"] mutableCopy] all is good.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way! I'm still not sure I understand why making a copy helps...

Comment: Please post the _real_ code: `namesAndEmails` cannot be the real code, as that will not compile!

Comment: @danyowdee No it will not compile. I didn't post the Person class that I use in the loop. Also from the Group class I only posted the namesAndEmails method from the implementation...

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to use the "Product->Analyze" feature. If you leaking or over releasing somewhere, it will probably give you the exact chain of events.

Secondly, I can't see the linking between your methods `nameAndEmails` and `emailGroup:`. Because I can't see the connection, I can't tell you if the autorelease is causing the problem.

Autoreleased objects get released when the the main run loop cycles. So it's very possible your `NSDictionary` is getting released. You could test this by doing anything from setting the memory location as a "watch" in the debugger to putting printing something in the console lines each time the runloop your in cycles (I made the assumption your in the main run loop, so correct me if that's not true).

Other things you can do to track the problem would be to use "Zombies" in instruments or `NSZombieEnable=YES` in your configuration

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to start by printing something to the log when the run loop cycles but I can't figure out how to do that. Any advice?

Comment: Sadly I do not anymore (the way i used to do it wouldn't work now). I was going to try and look it up, but I just haven't had the time.